# how to merge 2 data set?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge 2 datasets. I have tried different functions but I can't get the correct output.

One dataset is a subset of the other (bigger) one. I want to choose rows from the big one which have the same value in the second column of the smaller one.

I want to get rows in `df2` which have the same value in `SAMPNO` and `PERNO`

**Smaller one df1**

```
>    SAMPN     PERNO    other.column
>      1         2          10
>      1         3           9
>      2         2           8
>      2         4           7
```

**Bigger one df2**

```
>    SAMPN     PERNO     other.column
>      1         2            10
>      1         2             7
>      1         2             9
>      1         3             7
>      1         3             9
>      1         4             7
>      1         5             5
>      1         6             9
>      2         2             9
>      2         2             8
>      2         4             3
>      2         3             1
>      3         3             0
```

**Expected output**

```
> SAMPN     PERNO    other.column
>          1         2           10
>          1         2           7
>          1         2           9
>          1         3           9
>          1         3           7
>          2         2           8
>          2         2           9
>          2         4           7
>          2         4           3
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
     WithDriving<-merge( df2,df1,  all.y = TRUE)
     WithDriving<-merge( df1,df2 , all.x = TRUE)
```

These give me the rows of smaller dataset. (`#rows==#df1`) which is wrong because I want to find more rows from bigger data which have the same `SAMPN` and `PERNO`.

I have also tried

```
      WithDriving<-merge( df1,df2 , all.y = TRUE)
```

this one gives me the rows of the bigger one but it also gives some rows which do not have the same `SAMPN` and `PERNO` in any of the rows in `df1`.

Comment: is the combination of SAMPN and PERNO a unique identifier in both datasets?

Comment: yes in both I have these 2 columns

Comment: no - does: nrow( unique( df1[ , c( "SAMPN ","PERNO ")] )) == nrow( df1)

Comment: No it gives FALSE

Comment: you have to solve that first.  at least one data set has to have those variables as unique identifer

Comment: how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem.

```
d1 = apply(data[,1:2],1,paste,collapse="-")
d2 = apply(data2[,1:2],1,paste,collapse="-")
data3 = data2[d2%in%d1,]
> data3
   SAMPN PERNO other
1      1     2    10
2      1     2     7
3      1     2     9
4      1     3     7
5      1     3     9
9      2     2     9
10     2     2     8
11     2     4     3
```

We first paste the two columns separated by `-` in both dataframes. We then see which of the elementse in `d2` are in `d3` and keep those rows in the `data2` matrix.